# How to work (call)by bot telegram with php?instead in telegram app

Tags: telegram-bot

I build bot telegram.

Is possible to work/call/use bot in php ? Not build it. I want use bot.

i want use bot without telegram app.

is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you download php bot source on hosting and using via browser string.

**Must have:**

1. *Bot token*
2. *SSL certificate*

Comment: yes.I Know.
I Can Connect to Bot.But How Use Bot Without Telegram app?